# Nagios CheckProcState with command line

Tags: windows, java, nagios

I want to monitor a java process on a windows machine with nagios. On the windows server with process explorer I can see that the java process is started with "java -jar myApp.jar" in the command line. I've installed the NSClient++ and want to use the CheckProcState plugin.

```
check_nrpe -H 192.168.1.100 -p 5666 -c CheckProcState -a cmdLine ShowAll  "java.exe"=started
```

gives me

```
OK: java.exe: 1|'java.exe'=1;0;0
```

but if I also want to check the command line

```
check_nrpe -H 192.168.1.100 -p 5666 -c CheckProcState -a cmdLine ShowAll  "java.exe java -jar myApp.jar"=started
```

I get:

```
CRITICAL: java.exe java -jar myApp.jar: stopped (critical)|'java.exe ja'=0;0;0
```

How can I check the command line correctly with the CheckProcState plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [bug](http://www.nsclient.org/nscp/discussion/topic/805). I have tried with the latest version:

```
$ check_nrpe -H IP -p 5666 -c checkVersion
0.3.9.328 2011-08-16

check_nrpe -H IP -p 5666 -c checkProcState -a match=substr cmdLine ShowAll=long "gmond.conf"
CRITICAL: gmond.conf: stopped (critical)|'gmond.conf'=0;0;0

check_nrpe -H IP -p 5666 -c checkProcState -a match=regexp cmdLine ShowAll=long ".*gmond.exe.*gmond.conf.*"
CRITICAL: .*gmond.exe.*gmond.conf.*: stopped (critical)|'.*gmond.exe.*gmond.conf.*'=0;0;0
```

Both `match=substr` and `match=regexp` are return to `CRITICAL`, it seems that the `cmdLine` option is not working.

Comment: Do you know if there is another plugin that works with command line?